# Shape=() vector containing many values when printed

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am using tensorflow to develop a VAE, so the cost I am using for the model is ELBO (Evidence Lower Bound). In order to apply the error to the gradients, `reduce_mean()` has to be used in the last step so that the cost function returns a scalar.

```
def vae_cost(x_true, model, analytic_kl=False, kl_weight=4):
  x_true = tf.cast(x_true, tf.float32)
  z_sample, mu, sd = model.encode(x_true)
  x_recons_logits = model.decoder(z_sample)
  # compute mean squared error
  recons_error = tf.cast(
      tf.reduce_mean((x_true - x_recons_logits) ** 2, axis=[1, 2, 3]),
      tf.float32)
  # compute reverse KL divergence, either analytically 
  # or through MC approximation with one sample
  if analytic_kl:
    kl_divergence = -0.5 * tf.math.reduce_sum(
        1 + tf.math.log(tf.math.square(sd)) - tf.math.square(mu) - tf.math.square(sd),
        axis=1) # shape=(batch_size,)
  else:
    log_pz = normal_log_pdf(z_sample, 0., 1.) # shape=(batch_size,)
    logqz_x = normal_log_pdf(z_sample, mu, tf.math.square(sd))
    kl_divergence = logqz_x - log_pz

  elbo = tf.reduce_mean(-kl_weight * kl_divergence - recons_error)
  return -elbo
```

(Note: this is code I took from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/6-different-ways-of-implementing-vae-with-tensorflow-2-and-tensorflow-probability-9fe34a8ab981) and barely modified)

The model trains perfectly; there is no issue in that sense. What I am having problems with is the fact of *printing* the error. I have little knowledge of how tensorflow works internally, but I know you cannot use python's built-in `print()` function, since that prints the computation graph, if I am not mistaken. Therefore, `tf.print()` seemed to be the solution, but instead of a single value this is what shows up in the console:

```
2.72147369
2.37455082
3.83512926
2.00962853
2.3469491
3.15436459
2.25914431
2.40686131
2.98925924
2.75991917
1.94956458
3.1419673
2.06783676
2.53439474
2.18458319
2.31454301
1.79345393
1.81354737
2.27693963
1.60603094
2.71092319
1.90332329
2.64296
1.94370067
2.07476187
2.32125258
```

And then, if I use python's `print()`:

```
<tf.Tensor 'Neg:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
```

If the vector has shape=(), then how is it possible to get so many values with `tf.print()`? Am I actually confusing how this function works? In that case, how do I actually print the error? I would appreciate it if you could explain what `"Neg:0"` means as well. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The output of tf.print() is a list of values, one for each element in the input tensor. In this case, the input tensor is a vector with shape=(), so the output is a list of values, each corresponding to an element in the input vector.

Here is the revised code:

```
def vae_cost(x_true, model, analytic_kl=False, kl_weight=4):
  x_true = tf.cast(x_true, tf.float32)
  z_sample, mu, sd = model.encode(x_true)
  x_recons_logits = model.decoder(z_sample)
  # compute mean squared error
  recons_error = tf.cast(
      tf.reduce_mean((x_true - x_recons_logits) ** 2, axis=[1, 2, 3]),
      tf.float32)
  # compute reverse KL divergence, either analytically 
  # or through MC approximation with one sample
  if analytic_kl:
    kl_divergence = -0.5 * tf.math.reduce_sum(
        1 + tf.math.log(tf.math.square(sd)) - tf.math.square(mu) - tf.math.square(sd),
        axis=1) # shape=(batch_size,)
  else:
    log_pz = normal_log_pdf(z_sample, 0., 1.) # shape=(batch_size,)
    logqz_x = normal_log_pdf(z_sample, mu, tf.math.square(sd))
    kl_divergence = logqz_x - log_pz

  elbo = tf.reduce_mean(-kl_weight * kl_divergence - recons_error)
  return -elbo, kl_divergence, recons_error
```

Comment: I thought shape=() meant it would return a scalar, but thank you for explaining its true meaning. Nevertheless, why should also `kl_divergence` and `recons_error` be returned as well? Besides, what I cannot understand is the fact that I am getting many values from `reduce_mean` when it is supossed to reduce everything to a scalar.